# How to ensure uniqueness across multiple enums?

Tags: c#, .net, enums

I'm implementing Caching architecture for my application. I wan't the keys to be an enum driven value instead of passing keys from different modules. This will let me manage all my caching calls in one place (as everything specified in the enum is cached).

My enum definitions are as follows:

```
public enum ActionsTypeAEnum { SomthingFromACache, SomethingElseFromACache }
public enum ActionsTypeBEnum { SomthingFromBCache, SomethingElseFromBCache }
```

Now I have defined a `CacheManager` util class which has methods like GetCachedData, InsertCacheData, and so on...

I have a couple of questions:

1. How do I ensure that the enum values are unique across multiple enums?
2. In my InsertCacheData, I would like to have just 1 method which accepts values from any of the defined enums, instead of having multiple overloaded methods defined for this (as C# does not provide Enum inheritance, I cannot use a 'base' type enum as a method parameter)

How else can I architect my code to achieve the above tasks?

Comment: To my knowledge there is no way to associate two enums in this (or any) way. Why even have two, why not use the same enum (sans the A and B) for both - surely you know what cache you are talking to?

Comment: I cannot. This is because, the enums are used for caching at different places in code (like client tier, server tier, etc). And the place to Cache is defined by the Enum it belongs to.

Comment: Fair enough, but then why do they necessarily need to be similar?

Comment: So that I can handle and manage them with one CacheManager class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're simply moving beyond the capabilities of enums.  It might be time to move onto creating custom classes that simply emulate the behavior of enums that you're looking for:

```
public abstract class CacheAction
{
    //so it can't be inherited from elsewhere
    private  CacheAction() { }

    public class TypeA : CacheAction
    {
        private TypeA() { }
        public static readonly TypeA SomthingFromACache = new TypeA();
        public static readonly TypeA SomethingElseFromACache = new TypeA();
    }
    public class TypeB : CacheAction
    {
        private TypeB() { }
        public static readonly TypeB SomthingFromBCache = new TypeB();
        public static readonly TypeB SomethingElseFromBCache = new TypeB();
    }
}
```

This allows you to write the method:

```
public static void Foo(CacheAction action)
{
    if (action == CacheAction.TypeA.SomthingFromACache) { }
    else if (action == CacheAction.TypeA.SomethingElseFromACache) { }
    else if (action == CacheAction.TypeB.SomthingFromBCache) { }
    else if (action == CacheAction.TypeB.SomethingElseFromBCache) { }
    //this will only be hit by null unless you omit an option above
    else throw new ArgumentException("Invalid action provided");
}
```

Note that if it would help you, you can actually store some state within each of these actions.  You can give `CacheAction` a read only property based on some information set in the constructor, and then have each of the fixed instances set some data when they're created.  It could be an integer that you ensure is unique, it could be some string, an `Action` representing what to do, or whatever.  And by ensuring that it's exposed through the base class you would in fact allow methods like `Foo` to leverage polymorphism, rather than needing to check each of the types.

Comment: I like your approach, and also thought about it. However, when the application is too big and there are several things to cache, how should I ensure the Property Names (Ex: SomthingFromACache and SomthingFromBCache) are unique?

Comment: @Shankar The compiler ensures that for you.  You cannot have two fields of the same type have the same name.  If there are fields in different types with the same name then it's not a problem; the type name differentiates them for you.

Comment: The compiler does not ensure uniqueness across properties in 2 classes. Please look at the example I mentioned:  (Ex: SomthingFromACache and SomthingFromBCache). Thanks!

Comment: @Shankar And I specifically addressed that.  As I said, if the fields are in different types than the types themselves differentiate the fields.  They don't *need* to have the same names.  In fact, it may well be *appropriate* for them to have different names.  You'll still have an entry for each option in the `if/else if` chain, and there is no way for those different fields to be "confused" with each other in those checks; the fields with the same name in different classes are still different objects.

Comment: Great! I am convinced now. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can define a parent enum and use it to set values in "child" enums.

```
public enum ParentEnum
{
    A1 = 1, A2 = 2,
    B1 = 100, B2 = 101
}

public enum AEnum
{
    A1 = ParentEnum.A1,
    A2 = ParentEnum.A2
}
```

and similarly for B. I've used this technique successfully to extend enums before.